# While and do while loops

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm new to this site and also very new to Java and I'm trying to understand the do while loops

Question: What is the output and why?

```
public class DoWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1; 

        do { 
            System.out.println("i is : " + i); 
            i++; 
        } while(i < 1);  
    } 
}
```

I get that the output is "i is : 1" but I'm trying to understand why. It stops once it hits while because i isn't less that 1, right?

Just trying to get my head around it so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested it out?

Comment: Try to think like the computer. i++ makes i = 1 + 1 = 2. So we have to see if 2 < 1. 2 < 1 is false and it breaks out of loop. Suppose we had no i++, then we have to see see if 1 < 1. No ! 1 can't be < 1. So, it will still break out of loop.

Comment: Goldrush baby ! VVVVVVV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the output is 1 because in a do-while loop the statements within the do block are always executed at least once.

After the do block is executed the i value becomes 2 and the while block is not executed.

The difference between do-while and while is that do-while evaluates its expression at the bottom of the loop instead of the top. Therefore, the statements within the do block are always executed at least once

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. One more question: If it was just a while loop would the output still be the same?

Comment: If I understood right , I guess you are assuming the below code in the while block. Then the output will not be printed because the expression will be evaluated as false and the loop wont execute since i is initialized to 1 
while(i <1){
system.out.println("i is : " + i)
}

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Correct.

```
do { } while (condition);
```

This will perform the code at least once, regardless of the condition. After the first execution it will check the condition, which will evaluate to false (1 is not smaller than 1) and thus it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the output is

```
i is : 1
```

The [do-while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) will always execute at least once, because the condition isn't evaluated before the loop is entered; it's only evaluated at the end of each iteration.  This is in contrast to the `while` loop, whose condition is checked before the first iteration as well as after each iteration.

`i` is `1` at the start, then print occurs, then `i` is incremented to `2`.  Then the condition is evaluated -- it's `false`, so the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The output is just `1` becuase the do causes the loop to execute at least once, but the condition in the `while` doesn't aloow the loop to reiterate, because `i` is never less than 1

Answer (score 0):

It is no more 1

```
public class DoWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1; // i is 1

        do { 
            System.out.println("i is : " + i); //still i is 1
            i++; // this makes i = 2;
        } while(i < 1);  
    } 
}
```

if you notice the comments it is no more 1 after the first iteration